# How can you grab a video frame from an inputstream in java?

Tags: java, video, video-streaming, video-processing, javacv

I'm trying to generate a thumbnail from a video in java.

I have found the javacv library and can see that it can be used to grab frames

```
    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrab = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("");
    frameGrab.start();
    Frame frame = frameGrab.grabImage();

    Buffer[] image = frame.image;
```

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

This code requires the video to be a local file

But the video file is not local, I'm reading it as a stream from aws s3.

I don't want to save the video locally as disk space is limited...

How can this be done?

Comment: I came to this file http://javadox.com/org.bytedeco/javacv/0.8/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameGrabber.html - does it look like there is a stream constructor? I dont think so

Comment: You can pass the URL link in : new FFmpegFrameGrabber("url");
The link can be RTSP, CGI or other supported streams.